# Adobe iOS SDK crashes when returning to the foreground referencing a write to plist file

Tags: ios, multithreading, sdk, adobe

I'm having trouble reproducing the crash detailed below (got it from crash analytics/tracking). There always also appears to be another suspect looking thread running alongside the crashed thread at the same time on every instance of the crash reported:

Crashed Thread

```
0   CoreFoundation 0x2f9074be CFGetTypeID + 6
1   CoreFoundation 0x2f91e47b _flattenPlist + 47
2   CoreFoundation 0x2f91e57f _flattenPlist + 307
3   CoreFoundation 0x2f98257b __CFBinaryPlistWrite + 131
4   CoreFoundation 0x2f91e321 CFPropertyListWrite + 245
5   CoreFoundation 0x2f92e731 CFPropertyListWriteToStream + 145
6   CoreFoundation 0x2f92c39d _CFXPreferencesWritePlist + 269
7   CoreFoundation 0x2f92c28b -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSourceSynchronizer writePlistToDisk] + 131
8   CoreFoundation 0x2f929aef -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSourceSynchronizer synchronizeAlreadyFlocked] + 487
9   CoreFoundation 0x2f929905 -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSourceSynchronizer synchronize] + 21
10  CoreFoundation 0x2f929405 __79-[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSource synchronizeInBackgroundWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke + 101
11  libdispatch.dylib 0x3a656d53 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 11
12  libdispatch.dylib 0x3a65bcbd _dispatch_queue_drain + 489
13  libdispatch.dylib 0x3a658c6f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 43
14  libdispatch.dylib 0x3a65c5f1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 77
15  libdispatch.dylib 0x3a65c8dd _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 57
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3a787c17 _pthread_wqthread + 299
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3a787adc start_wqthread + 8
```

Other suspect thread (that always runs at the same time and looks like it's related):

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3a70faa0 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib 0x3a65b513 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 139
2   CoreFoundation 0x2f94424d CFPreferencesAppSynchronize + 265
3   Foundation 0x3032e91d -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) synchronize] + 25
4   MailOnline 0x00280897 ADBLifecycleStart + 2495
5   CoreFoundation 0x2f998f41 _CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 13
6   CoreFoundation 0x2f90cda9 _CFXNotificationPost + 1721
7   Foundation 0x302f7cc5 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 73
8   UIKit 0x3246747f -[UIApplication _sendWillEnterForegroundCallbacks] + 155
9   UIKit 0x3240c88b -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] + 927
10  UIKit 0x3220b613 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1883
11  UIKit 0x3220adf9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 73
12  UIKit 0x3226f405 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 617
13  GraphicsServices 0x34878b55 _PurpleEventCallback + 609
14  GraphicsServices 0x3487873f PurpleEventCallback + 35
15  CoreFoundation 0x2f9a1847 _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 35
16  CoreFoundation 0x2f9a17e3 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 347
17  CoreFoundation 0x2f99ffaf __CFRunLoopRun + 1407
18  CoreFoundation 0x2f90a769 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
19  CoreFoundation 0x2f90a54b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
20  GraphicsServices 0x348776d3 GSEventRunModal + 139
21  UIKit 0x32269891 UIApplicationMain + 1137
22  MailOnline 0x000cd18b main (main.m:16)
23  libdyld.dylib 0x3a66bab7 start + 3
```

When debugging the running program it appears that the Adobe Mobile SDK we use for tracking listens to the return to foreground event fired by the OS and then calls synchronize on the NSUserDefaults (see Other suspect thread). The synchronize then breaks off into another thread (the crashed thread) but then it crashes for some reason when trying to write to a plist file.

I cannot reproduce the crash. We are using v4.0 of the Adobe Mobile Library iOS SDK so if anyone else has had similar crashes with these SDKs then please help!? Or if anyone has any suggestions for steps to make this crash more likely to happen (e.g. I've tried writing to plist constantly when the SDK runs to see if it was a threading issue but with no luck) then please advise...

NOTE: This issue is still happening on newer devices running iOS 7 but still does not ever occur on devices running iOS 8.0 or 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: At WWDC this year, Apple Engineers confirmed that NSUserDefaults got a total rewrite. After some testing, this issue appears to have been resolved and is no longer reproducible running iOS 8.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is due to a race condition inside of NSUserDefaults itself.  The following code snippet will reproduce the issue in an isolated scenario(You'll need to let this code run for 15-30 seconds to expose the issue):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        while(true) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: @"value" forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"blah%d",i]];
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"blah%d",i]];
            }
        }
    });
```

Other people have reported this issue, clearest example of this being [this post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/773176#773176) on the apple developer forums(registration required).

My recommendation would be to check your code for any significant read/write cycles into NSUserDefaults.  If you need to do a massive amount of changes or updates to data, you probably want to roll your own persistence layer instead of NSUserDefaults until this issue is resolved by Apple.

The ADBLifecycleStart method is a red-herring in this scenario.  This code runs on it's own queue, and will probably be living (or at least caught by a full thread dump) most of the time.  The ADBLifeCycleStart method makes a worst case total of 13 writes to NSUserDefaults, followed by a synchronize.

Answer (score 0):

Henry,

On launch, the sdk updates some items stored in NSUserDefaults. After those items are updated, NSUserDefaults attempts to synchronize which updates the NSUserDefaults plist. It looks like the application is crashing at the point when the device is attempting to update that plist. After some investigation it seems that this can happen for a couple different reasons. 1) If zombie mode is turned on (causing memory to never be freed) and your app reaches 4GB per-process, 2) The nsuserdefaults plist has become corrupt.

-Hunter

Comment: hpeterson thanks for getting back on this one.

1.) We do not have zombie mode turned on. We have never used it for this app so we can fairly confidently rule out this as a potential issue.

2.) Our app should be able to access every NSUserDefaults key/value pair saved under our app bundle identifier. Therefore this is a scenario we can run through and debug. I will investigate this potential issue and let you know if this is the case.

Many thanks for the suggestions!